# Installing python2.6 on LinuxMint

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

I have LinuxMitn with python2.7 and python3.4. But for some specific application that company develops i need python2.6. Can someone please tell me how to correctly install it?

Comment: You can always compile from source.

Comment: If your company requires you to develop for Python 2.6, why aren't they providing you with an appropriate environment development?

Comment: compile from source and create a symlink so that `python26` points to this version of python. be careful so that `python` doesn't point to version 2.6

Answer (score 1):

Download & compile:

```
wget http://www.python.org/path/to/Python-2.6.x.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.6.x.tgz  
cd Python-2.6.x
```

Compile:

```
./configure  
make  
sudo make install
```

When you run application make sure you are typing full path of your python2.6 binary:

`/usr/local/bin/python2.6`

Or If you don't need python3.4 then simple you can rename old binary and create symlink to new python2.6 ( it will help you to install python2.6 related module by default)

```
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4.old
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also check [the deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) for the solution, but I have found that [python](http://www.python.org) builds fairly well as well, @Satish gives a good set of instructions to do this.